# Txt file contains bin characters which doesn't render properly in vim

Tags: linux, vim

The txt file with the content opens properly in the GUI editor (i am using sublime). But in vim, it appears like this, now i can't do the grep in this file. When i use less, it says "may be a binary file". How do i convert this to proper text file. Any idea why these strange characters are appearing?

Y^@ear|d^@o^@n^@o^@r^@c^@o^@d^@e^@|^@d^@o^@n^@o^@r^@n^@a^@m^@e^@|^@a^@g^@e^@n^@c^@y^@c^@o^@d^@e^@|^@a^@g^@e^@n^@c^@y^@n^@a^@m^@e^@|^@c^@r^@s^@i^@d    ^@|^@p^@r^@o^@j^@e^@c^@t^@n^@u^@m^@b^@e^@r^@|^@i^@n^@i^@t^@

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a plain text file stored in Unicode UTF-16 LE, where each Unicode codepoint stored as one or two 16-bit code units.

If the text itself is primarily ASCII-only (all codepoints ≤ U+00FF), the result looks as if a NUL byte was inserted after every byte, if you're viewing the file from an UTF-16-incapable editor.

In command line, use `iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 < file.txt > file-new.txt` to fix it.

In Vim, you can use `:e ++enc=utf-16le` to re-open the file using the proper encoding.

If possible, **tell Sublime to save files as UTF-8**, which will be much more compatible with various tools. (In Vim: `:set fileencoding=utf-8 | w`)

Comment: Actually, ASCII text would be all code points ≤ U+007F.

Comment: Right, miscalculated.

Comment: Thanks. I also found a command that stripped all the unknown char from the file 
`tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < input-file`

Comment: @Anjesh – That's not exactly a good way to "fix" it; it just happens to work because the text is _mostly_ ASCII. For anything else it'd just end up as garbage.